# Passing data as PutExtras in KIVY app ResultIntent

Tags: python, c#, android, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to pass the outputs of my Python Kivy app (1 csv and 1 png) to PutExtras in the app's ResultIntent. I'm unsure how to operationalize them in my Python script. Below I've included a extremely short version of the .py file. The .kv file that goes along with it is blank because the purpose of the app is to produce the two outputs to be used by another application. I used Buildozer to convert it to an APK file.

```
from kivy.app import App
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter, ImageFont
import pandas as pd


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self): 
        try:
                    #All of the code used to construct the image and csv go here                

                    #Savings Image and CSV
                    image.save('image.png')
                    elements_data.to_csv('elements_data.csv', index=False)

        except IOError: 
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Also, a coworker showed me how it would work using C#, but I'm unfamiliar with that language and how it would translate to Python/Kivy.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
byte[] image = GetImageBytes();
byte[] csv = GetCSVBytes();

resultIntent.PutExtra("image", image);
resultIntent.PutExtra("csv", csv);

SetResult(Result.Ok, resultIntent);
```

Any tips would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What is the version of python and c# that you are using?

Comment: Ultimately you need to read the putExtra documentation and pass appropriate arguments. [Here](https://github.com/inclement/Kivy-keyboard-tester/blob/master/keyboardtester/main.py#L64) is an old example where I've done it before - I don't think there was any gotcha beyond that.

Comment: @SxolarBit Python Version 3.8.3 . I'm not actually using C#, nor do I know it, but that piece of code was given to me to get an idea about what I should do.

Comment: @inclement Thank you! I'll try this out.